# Попытка запустить отладку в gdb завершается с кодом 1

Tags: linux, powershell, gdb

Пытаюсь освоить gdb по туториалу из книжки.
Написал простейший *helloworld* на C, скомпилил GCC без дополнительных аргументов.

Запускаю, `gdb -q ./a.out`, Затем когда я делаю

```
(gdb) b main 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x113d
(gdb) run
Starting program: /run/media/source/a.out 
exec: The term 'exec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
During startup program exited with code 1.
```

Тут явно ошибка, связанная с тем что что-то в gdb запускается в **powershell** а не bash (у меня дефолтный шелл - powershell, но дело происходит на linux). Однако эта ошибка точно так же воспроизводится и при запуске из bash. Как её решить?

Comment: `(No debugging symbols found in ./a.out)` — это из-за того, что просто без отладочной информации скомпилировал всё... скорми gcc ключик `-g` и будет ок... по проблеме — `SHELL=/bin/bash gdb -q ./a.out` должно помочь, но что это за франкенштейн такой?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, помогло. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: А чего такого в powershell? Нравится он мне, использую.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, более интересно с DWARF конретно под Gdb: `-g -ggdb`.

Comment: @bearpro, я сначала почему-то решил, что под «дефолтным» подразумевалось `ln -s /path/to/powershell /bin/sh`... отсюда и некоторое недоумение, как оно вообще работает... а в качестве логин-шелла, в принципе, ничего критичного, действительно, быть не должно... разве что случайные утилиты скрипты будут переставать работать...

Comment: @0andriy, и какие плюшки оно даёт?

Comment: @Fat-Zer https://stackoverflow.com/q/668962/2511795

Comment: @0andriy, там ничего адекватного не написано...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как мельком [замечается](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html) в документации gdb (вольный перевод):

> На Unix-системах GDB запускает ваши программы с помощью оболочки, указанной в переменной среды `SHELL`, если она задана (или `/bin/sh` в противном случае).

т.о. для корректной работы при запуске gdb в переменной среды `SHELL` должна быть указана маломальски posix-совместимая оболочка. это можно сделать, запустив `gdb` как-то так:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash gdb -q ./a.out
```